# CAN Bus: Nodes powered by different Potential Sources

Tags: power-supply, can

There was one similar question asked in 2018, but there was detail lacking. So here goes:

I have an engine running a J1919 CAN bus about 15 m away from an Engine Info Display that receives CAN-bus data. Both use J1939. The CAN lines are 'CAN_H', 'CAN_L', and 'CAN_SHIELD'

The engine is powered from a different battery than the display. These two batteries aren't always connected, hence the question asking about nodes being on a different potential source. The batteries are both 24 V.

The 0 V rail, however, is common between all devices and the negative battery terminals.

The only useful info I could find is from Wikipedia; there is a paragraph on ISO 11898-2 that says the transceivers are isolated from the node hosts (I assume both are in the 'node' device) and a node has its own linear regulator that draws from the 'universal supply bus'.

Essentially I'm asking whether the transceiver at a node is completely isolated from the rest of the node, so the supply voltage source to the actual node device (e.g. engine display or engine) does not matter.

Or is there a direct electrical connection when the bus is driven and I have to galvanically isolate two CAN bus segments with a suitable repeater?

Thank you

Edit 1: The display model is the Murcal PV101-C from Murphy. It doesn't mention anything on requiring/omitting isolation.

[image: PV101-C Murcal Engine display]

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- Either you use galvanically isolated CAN bus, in which case you need a plan for providing power and signal ground for the secondary - they need to come from somewhere. Ideally you provide a raw 12V/24V etc voltage to all nodes and let each node have a dedicated regulator. If there are no long distances, you may get away with a centralized regulator though I'd be sceptic against such a design in an automotive application.

  The isolation itself can be done with specialized CAN transceivers, digital isolators or optocouplers.
- Or you don't use isolation, in which case you still need a clean CAN_GND shared between all nodes. This ground should be routed on each PCB so that it is kept away from dirty power grounds etc. You should not mess it up with shield or chassis either. (Normally one end of the shield will be connected to chassis and the other is not connected.)

Either way, you need a dedicated signal ground CAN_GND, as specified by the ISO standard. This is particularly important in automotive and industrial applications where motors, coils or valves etc are present.

Also note that the tolerated absolute maximum potential difference on the CANH/CANL pins varies quite a lot depending on CAN transceiver. In any event, your car ground potential will be nowhere near the household mains or laptop battery grounds, so if you plan to troubleshoot your CAN bus at all - which involves a PC - you need a signal ground for that alone.

Comment: Not using isolation seems like the best option. The wiring of the CAN bus is essentially the same as the diagram that I included. There is only CAN_H, CAN_L and CAN_SHIELD.

It is a little unclear for me where the engine's CAN_GND connection is. The diagram above shows that the CAN_SHIELD is connected on both ends to the respective devices. If it is as @Jeroen3 pointed out, CAN_GND and CAN_SHIELD is not the same thing, then the only other possibility that I can think of then is that the display and engine's connection to the common 0V of the battery acts as CAN_GND.

Comment: from the above, a correction:  "...It is a little unclear for me where the engine or display's CAN_GND connection is"

Comment: @crathob Yes there's lots of crappily designed CAN hardware without dedicated signal grounds. The shield is not it, even though it is typically connected to ground. Reserving a pin for a shield but not for signal ground is pretty senseless. Lets hope there are no engines or other such noisy things anywhere near their CAN design... At least when you get lots of strange CAN error frames out of the blue soon as you activate the engine, you know the reason why.

Comment: That cleared up my questions. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Many CAN tranceivers are isolated, but if that is the case in your display remains to be seem. If the display has no other exposed metal parts, then it is most like inherently isolated due to using any double isolated ac/dc power supply.

For example, any Kvaser interface is isolated. As you can recognize on the isolation gap on [their PCB](https://www.kvaser.com/product/kvaser-leaf-light-hs-v2-cb/).
[image]

Also many devices using CAN bus have isolation if they are *sold separately*.
This is typical, **but not required by the standard.**

The reason for this is that it adds cost that you don't need. In a car, where everything is powered from the same battery, isolation has no benefit.

In large industrial machine where there can be many ac/dc converters or even generators, isolation makes the grounding (CAN_GND) easier.

Even though CAN is differential, it is not balanced. It still requires CAN_GND to keep common mode voltage in check. In a car this is just negative battery terminal and chassis. On mains it can be mains earth, with risk of ground loop. So you add isolation to break the ground loops.

Do you need to isolate your display? Read the manual, or measure ohms from CAN_GND to mains earth/dc-in.

Comment: I see the isolation in your Kvaser interface. The manual for the display does not say anything about isolation (post updated with specifics). I'm still designing the system so I can't measure the 'CAN-SHIELD' to chassis/earth. I take it from your message that the system would work but the isolation will simply prevent any issues with ground loops.

Comment: @crathob this screen is not isolated, there is no CAN_GND pin, only CAN_SHIELD which is not the same. You can only use this screen if both battery grounds are connected.

Comment: I see, thanks. In my original post I said the battery grounds (negative terminals) are connected but the positive terminals are separate. The question is more about the difference between the positive terminals on the batteries.

Comment: Ah - you mean both the engine and display uses the 0V (from the DC input) as CAN_GND (since it is not explicitly a pinout). Therefore it has to be common (and it is). The positive terminal question from the comment above is still open

Comment: @crathob Whatever power sources you have is irrelevant as long as the grounds are all the same.

Comment: "In a car, where everything is powered from the same battery, isolation has no benefit." Of course it does -  you don't want to mix up the dirty power ground with digital signal ground. A car power ground will have all manner of currents, surges and noise. The starter engine/ignition is particularly nasty.

Comment: @Lundin isolation is not the answer for all your noise problems. But power supply isolation can reduce loops in this regard. You still tie CAN_gnd to chassis though.

Comment: No but it certainly helps in case the noisy crap is designed by someone else and you have no way to fix that other design. It also helps when someone messes up the wiring and connects 24VDC to your CAN lines.

Comment: And yeah in the end CAN_GND will be connected to chassis, but you should make that connection according to some rationale, like only make the connection close to where the supply enters your product, or outside it.